# How to compare time using country names?

Tags: c#, asp.net, timezone

i have a database where in a table user saves Country name and Time, another user checks his time by querying his database, i want to show the user what time is it in his country matching the time he searched. how to do that in c#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible using given data, since in general country can have multiple time zones (e.g. there is 9 time zones in Russia). You only option is to require exact time zone info from the user in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I will resolve your specific scenario by saving the offset from UTC/GMT time in my database along with the country name. And adjust the time according to the offset while displaying.

Comment: can i do like this,when user enters a particular time,it is converted to UTC time and saved into the DB with country name, when other user compares his time with his time, that UTC time will then be converted to local time ? and i dont know about this timezone, which class it is i should use in c# ?

Comment: All you need is add the offset from your datbase.